# Is there any Mathematica.SE promo planned for the 2012 Wolfram Technology Conference?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Does anyone intend (or should there be an effort) to promote Mathematica SE at this year´s Tech Conference in October in Champaign? Seems like a pretty good opportunity to do so...

**Update:**

The conference is approaching and most potential attendees will probably have made up their mind on whether to go or not. Since @rm- rf could not attend, SE extended the generous offer to support promotion and supply swag to me (many thanks, @Aarthi!)

So I´d like to pick up the ball and ask about:

- Who will be attending? Anyone up for pre-conference drinks or similar?
- Any good ideas to make attendees aware what an excellent resource Mathematica.SE is?

I´ll commence by putting up some answers/ideas as a starting point... any suggestions on how to organize this thread better would be most welcome.

Comment: Is there any SE assistance for users wanting to attend for the 2012 Wolfram Technology Conference? Seems like a pretty good opportunity to do so...

Comment: Jin said there were plans and that the community team would get in touch w/ us

Comment: @Verde now there´s a thought ;-)

Comment: @YvesKlett just refining yours :D

Comment: @Verde We're looking into it, but we can't make an offer without gauging some interest! :D We'd *like* to support this community, even if it's assisting partially, but we can't do anything unless someone starts a post like this one. :)

Comment: @Aarthi Nice to know that! I'm not able to go this year, but I hope someone from this community could. I'm sure the site can grab quite a few talented newcomers by getting some exposure, and this conference is the better showroom

Comment: @Verde I agree! I hope some young turks pick up the ball on this one. :D

Answer (score 13):

Two weeks ago (to be precise [July 25](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2234?m=5498044#5498044) and [July 26](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2234?m=5513766#5513766)), I informally checked in chat whether there would be interest in going to the Tech Conference. Unfortunately and probably due to the inappropriateness of the location, it didn't draw massive attention at the time (apart from the commenters above, who don't seem to be remember anything), so I planned to post a formal Meta here. This Meta has to be in the format described in the SO Meta post [How can I get Stack Exchange to send me to a conference?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132282/how-can-i-get-stack-exchange-to-send-me-to-a-conferen) and the current post here could be a preparation for that.

The SE team has been hinting that we would have good chances being sponsored and I think the  [Wolfram Tech Conference](http://www.wolfram.com/events/technology-conference/2012/) (October 17-19, 2012) would be the ultimate platform to demonstrate our new Mathematica site. The audience consists of many seasoned Mathematica enthusiasts and professionals and a presentation of Mathematica.SE there would draw high level content and expertise to our site.

I attended the conference last year and found it very interesting and worthwhile and it gave me the opportunity to meet in real life many of the people I had only known from mathgroup or stackoverflow.

**I don't think I have time to attend this year, but I would support the proposal of anyone from our community who has been contributing significantly to this site.**

Comment: you mean, 6 weeks ago...

Comment: @R.M Actually, his vacation took much of a toll on him and he lost an entire month..

Comment: @R.M time goes fast but not that fast, corrected.

Comment: I think **"contributing significantly"** is almost but not quite completely unlike subjective tea

Comment: @verde Agree. That's a term TBD, but I thought I shouldn't do that on my own. The Meta says "community leaders". A mixture of having the founder medal, a long presence here (say more than 50% of the days), and a rep over 5000 (all negotiable) may do. OTOH, I don't see many candidates so far.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I think that is because there is no perception (yet) of any involvement from SE. I can't go this year, but if I could, I would not start asking for support until the other party shows some porosity.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I agree with what belisarius said above. I'm not writing a pitch and meta post only for SE to come and say, "Sorry guys, you're new on the block. We decided to spend all our moolah on [gaming.se] yet again."

Comment: @Verde As I said before both above and in chat, SE has shown signs of potential commitment. You seem to ignore that. Specifically, we (or more precisely mr.Wizard and J.M, as I was on vacation) were visited in our Mathematica mod room and we were told: "So uh, I heard Mathematica is having a conference. Y'all may wish to make a meta post asking who's attending; SE meetup at MMA Conference 2012 maybe? depending on how that pans out, we might be able to point them at this: [the above referenced Meta post]"

Comment: @R.M comment above also for you. The pitch is for later; first I'd like to hear if there are any plans (however vague) at all.

Comment: Ok, I'm interested and will write a post. Only a comment for now, because I'm on a vacation in NYC and have sporadic net access.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Sorry, I was only aware of an aside comment made by Jin. I have no idea about who or when those sayings were made. Perhaps I missed some comments in chat or a post

Answer (score 3):

**Attendees** (please edit as you see fit):

**Update**: If you got not t-shirt or such yet - there will be swag (thanks to @Aarthi!)

@Yves: Will arrive on Monday, 15th. Will be jetlagged but should be presentable and ready for social interaction. **New: If you want to get in touch, have a look at my profile page.**

@rcollyer: will arrive in the morning on Tuesday, the 16th. Likely will be sleep deprived. Maybe up for lunch.

@Leonid Shifrin: will arrive in the evening on Monday, 15th. The condition should be pretty much the same as for @Yves (but perhaps a bit more jetlagged).

@Murta: Will arrive on Monday, 15th.

Comment: Of course if the top user swag arrives in time, that´ll make identifying suspects that much easier...

Comment: As far as swag goes, the process of sending it out was taken care of last week. What that means for you not being in the US, I don't know. So, you may not get to wear the super-secret identification badges like the rest of us, but we can always hope.

Answer (score 1):

Would anyone have a good idea on an entertaining MMA.SE related 5min presentation?

> Similar to Pecha Kucha, the Accelerate session consists of informal,
>   five-minute presentations on a subject of your choosing using Wolfram
>   technologies. Examples of topics from last year include: "Climate
>   Change from a Geological Perspective", "Dynamics of Decision
>   Processes", "Parametric Geometry", and "Guesstimates Engine."
>
> The Accelerate session was one of our attendees' favorites last year,
>   and if you're a part of it, it's sure to be even better this year. You
>   can send submissions to Michael Squeo (msqueo@wolfram.com) until
>   October 8. Acceptable files for presentations are Mathematica
>   notebooks and CDF documents, PDFs, or PowerPoint presentations. Space
>   is limited, so get your submissions in as soon as you can!

I did one last year and it was good fun. I could offer to submit one, but would like to plumb the community for juicy input or even better a set of slides. Perhaps some best-of-MMA.SE digest?

Comment: This will probably have to include some xkcd references ;-)

Answer (score 0):

We should be able to blog on our findings. Who would like to join forces? (If someone could brief me on how to blog for MMA.SE, please get in touch!)

Comment: Please register on the blog at `http://mathematica.blogoverflow.com/wp-login.php` (click on the login at dashboard link). Once you do that, I'll set up your account so that you can contribute (I'm admin on the blog). I'll brief you on how to edit, etc. in the blog chatroom (sometime later in the day, as I have to leave now)

Comment: @rm-rf excellent. Registered. Will be leaving soon, so perhaps some time tomorrow?

Comment: I converted your account to that of a contributor. Please take a look around the WP dashboard and familiarize yourself with the layout. There are some [very brief](http://mathematica.blogoverflow.com/?p=142&preview=true) tips here, but mostly it is the same as the site. You can ping me anytime if you have questions :)