# Is anyone here going to the Wolfram Technology Conference?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

> Related: [Is there any Mathematica.SE promo planned for the 2012 Wolfram Technology Conference?](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/607/is-there-any-mathematica-se-promo-planned-for-the-2012-wolfram-technology-confer)

The other question asks if there's any sort of promotional work being planned for it.

I'm asking if any of you are **already planning on attending**. I'd love to send some items for these users to give away if possible.

If you're attending the conference, and you'd be interested in helping promote Mathematica.SE, please answer this meta post with **which dates you plan to be at the conference, as well as which talks/panels you plan on attending!**

**Note!** If you'd like to be sponsored to attend the conference, please see this post: [How can I get Stack Exchange to send me to a conference?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132282/how-can-i-get-stack-exchange-to-send-me-to-a-conference/)

Answer (score 20):

I'll throw my hat in the ring... I'd like to attend the Wolfram Technology Conference and would like to be sponsored (I cannot attend otherwise). I'm a student in the U.S., and would like to attend 17—19th of Oct (i.e., only the conference and not the pre/post events).

I'm fairly active on the site and participate regularly in both, answering questions, and community moderation. This conference is probably the most relevant to the *Mathematica* community and it would be a good opportunity to get some new users (most of them possibly at the intermediate to expert level). I believe I can do a good job at explaining what this site is about, who it is for, the policies, community aspect, moderation, chat, etc. and especially about where it stands wrt the alternative that everyone's familiar with — MathGroup. It would also be great to meet in person some of the regulars here whom I only know via SE.

I can also blog about the conference and the sessions at [our blog](http://mathematica.blogoverflow.com), summing up my experiences (one for each day of the conference would be a good number), perhaps even live tweet certain events and happenings from the [@stackmma](http://twitter.com/stackmma) twitter account (maybe will have to work an arrangement with the team, since control over this account is not typically handed to users/mods/community).

---

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to everyone that supported my application for sponsorship to attend the conference. SE was very generous and agreed to fully cover the costs of registration, accommodation and per diem for the duration of stay. Unfortunately, the cost of the airfare (which was not being covered), was more than what I can afford to spend as a student at this point in time. I would've grabbed SE's offer in an instant had the situation been different, but for now, I've decided to withdraw my application so that other active members of the community can be sponsored. I strongly support Yves' application and also highly encourage others to apply!

Comment: Big +1. You definitely should go!

Comment: I can't think of a more qualified representative than you! And photos would be nice, for those that can't get there themselves.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin and cormullion, thanks for the vote of confidence!

Comment: I'm tempted to upvote your answer showing support for your candidature. However, you are not offering neither perks nor bribes. You badly need an accelerated crash course on politics.

Comment: @Verde I always forget about the Argentinian mafia...

Comment: Go, hypnotoad! The official deadline for abstracts was August 1st, but perhaps it is possible to still squeeze a MMA.SE abstract in with some help at WRI?

Comment: @YvesKlett I'm not sure about that... it would be nice though. Are you giving a talk this year too?

Comment: I submitted an abstract and hope it goes through (not about MMA.SE, though). There might be some very nice ways to stage a live MMA.SE session (perhpaps with some community standing by to impress the audience with witty comments and such).

Comment: I'll be glad to promote whatever promotional material you need at the confs. e.g. MMA.se branded t-shirts, stickers, banners etc

Comment: @Jin swag is always nice. :)

Comment: All hail the hypnotoad! Wait, what am I voting for?

Comment: Hello! I'm glad you're interested in being sponsored to attend. Please follow the instruction in [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132282/how-can-i-get-stack-exchange-to-send-me-to-a-conference/) for the next stage of the sponsorship process. It sounds like the community believes sending you would be an excellent investment. I now need you to email us (see the link) with some further information. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Aarthi Thanks! I'll contact you with the details soon

Comment: You should try to get in touch with WRI regarding a talk / submission / presentation possibility.

Comment: Aaand we will have to work on a remote control access so all your supporters get to puppet you around for a bit...

Comment: @YvesKlett are you sure that isn't already set up? After all, [We are Mr.Wizard](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/156/52). :)

Comment: That's a great pity that you won't be able to make it. This would be a great thing for the community, and I was also personally hoping to meet you  there.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Me too! I was hoping to meet several of you folks at the conference, but not to worry; I'll definitely make it to the conference some way or the other within the next year or two :)

Comment: I very much hope so. By the way, if you have some stuff to give a talk at the conference (that is, if you are a speaker), I've heard from a friend that in the past WRI sponsored speakers, fully or partially. Don't know if this is still so these days, though. But shouldn't be hard to find out.

Comment: @Leonid The abstract deadlines have long passed and the acceptances are also out (and the schedule is probably fixed by now). WRI might sponsor speakers... established speakers like Mark M., maybe ;) I don't have very many interesting things to talk about _Mathematica_ yet, but it hopefully won't be that way for long :) Thanks for the continued support!

Comment: No problem :-). I am sure you'll make it next time. Also, the coverage of the conf. keeps improving from year to year, a large percent of the talks gets recorded and becomes available after the conference online. Also, it might be a good idea if some of the participants would make a blog post on our blog reporting some interesting things they learned at the conference.

Comment: Also very sorry to hear that - I´d say SE will be missing out an excellent ambassador.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin it might be helpful if attendees would come forward and confess here. Right now I count two (you and me) ;-)

Comment: @YvesKlett Yes, I do confirm - as of now, I plan to come to the conference. I hope there will be more of us there.

Comment: @R.M I wanted to write to you about something and was looking for your email address but did not find it in my records. Could you send me a message on my gmail account (in my profile)? Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

I´ll be attending as well, and will give a talk. The programme is not out yet, so no specifics. Although I would not be averse to some sponsoring, I fully support @R.M´s (and any other eminent and merited members) application!

Of course, I´ll be happy to surreptitiously distribute any swag delivered to me ;-)

And - I will try to grab a pic the meatspace avatar of hypnotoad... anyone else attending? Should be great fun to have a BoF session or such.

**Update:** Since my funding is lining up and R.M probably won´t be able to attend, I´d also encourage other members to apply quickly.

Comment: Since you promised photographs, you get my vote! :)

Comment: Double vote if you promise a photo of @R.M with NKS [in his hands.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K9AsA0cY8qg)

Comment: @Verde I´ll bring my copy (even if it is a heavy transatlantic burden and probably causing some global warming) and club him if he is unwilling.

Comment: Noooo, no pictures. Of course, you'll all be hypnotized anyway...

Comment: See you there. My flight info was confirmed, yesterday.