# Wolfram Technology Conference 2013 - Sponsorship Proposal

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Dear friends of the *Mathematica* persuasion, October is nearing and one rather obvious  possibility to get personally in touch with WRI developers and *Mathematica* users at the same time in a big way (and make new users aware of this site) is the [**Wolfram Technology Conference**](http://www.wolfram.com/events/technology-conference/2013/) in Champaign, IL from **October 21-23**.

I have been to this conference several times and can highly recommend it, both from a professional and personal point of view ([2012](https://www.wolfram.com/events/technology-conference/2012/), [2011](https://www.wolfram.com/events/technology-conference/2011/), [...](https://www.google.com/search?q=wolfram+technology+conference&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:de:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gws_rd=cr&ei=SPYmUuSaE4WUtAbczIC4Cw#channel=fflb&q=wolfram+tech+conference&revid=1411111435&rls=org.mozilla:de:official)). Additionally, this year marks the 25th anniversary of the launch of *Mathematica*, so the good people at WRI are bound to make sure of some special events as well.

Last year StackExchange offered [support](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/618/is-anyone-here-going-to-the-wolfram-technology-conference) to help send a member of *Mathematica*.SE to the conference, and you can have a look at some results of that [here](http://mathematica.blogoverflow.com/2012/10/wolfram-technology-conference-2012/). After my very positive experience last year (thanks, folks!), it should be worth to have another go at bolstering the *Mathematica*.SE percentage in Champaign.

So please post an **answer** to this question containing your arguments why you would like to to go to Champaign and receive SE support, what you would contribute etc.. **Simply posting "yes" will not be helpful, you need to sell your case to SE and show the benefit to the site.**

**Please read this [Q&A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132282/how-can-i-get-stack-exchange-to-send-me-to-a-conference) on how best to further our/your chances to get support**

Quoting:

- **Who** is going?
- **What** conference is it, and what will you be doing there, besides attending?
- **When** is the conference running? We need at least a month’s lead time to help you get your approval. If you’re under or near that before posting, you might want to think about next year instead.
- **Where** is the conference located and how do you intend to get there?
- **Why** should the community approve you to go to this sponsorship? More importantly, why should the community approve going to this specific conference? Basically, what will you do to bring this learning back to the community?

**... and look at [last year´s thread](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/618/131) to get an idea.**

**Also, please don´t be too shy, because the conference is nearing quickly.**

**PS**: Attendants who are already comfortably booked should also post a comment just to get an idea who will be there in any case. Also, getting swag in form of pens, sticker or even t-shirts should be possible, but someone should volunteer to distribute that during the conference.

Comment: Comfortably booked. See you there.

Comment: @rcollyer nice! Although my situation right now is rather unclear, not sure if I´ll be able to attend...

Comment: Well that's too bad. If you have the time, put in a proposal, and I'll upvote it. We need our raining snippet champion there! :)

Comment: @rcollyer I´m feeling kinda thick - whut is a raining snippet champion?

Comment: I have no idea what it is called, but the 140 character code contest.

Comment: Ahh, the Oneliner contest. I was proud of my window havoc one last year, but there was no blog like in 2010 and 2011...

Comment: Is there anyone who is attending passing by South Bend, IN? :-) (Amtrak looks fine except for the transit times.)

Comment: Would love to go but since it's by vote, I'm sure someone with more reputation score and skill will receive the votes

Comment: @RHall no-one has applied, yet, so it looks like you stand a good chance to me.

Comment: @RHall please apply - let´s have some action around here.

Comment: @rcollyer speaking of the one-liner contest Simon Woods needs to submit some enhancement of the `GradientFilter` animation.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I must have missed that discussion, could you post a link?

Comment: @rcollyer look in chat: 9 times starred!

Comment: @YvesKlett I rarely run random bits of code, but that is so cool! Now 10 times starred, and pinned.

Comment: Application sent!  Thanks for the encouragement!

Comment: @Szabolcs if you can make it to Gary, I can get you the rest of the way.

Comment: I'd quite like to go, but I live 8,600 miles away.  Extra for experts: use Mathematica to figure out where I live.

Comment: @RHall I cannot see your answer here (which doubles as application and will be voted upon)...

Comment: @YvesKlett based on the post an application must be submitted and voted upon.(done)  I have answered that I wanted to go. Is there another requirement?

Comment: @RHall as far as I understand (from last year) the "applicaton" is an answer to this question and will be voted on as such in the regular SE fashion. That will also be useful if tseveral people apply.

Comment: @Kuba how about you?

Comment: I am also interested in going myself.

Comment: @RHall I can make it to Gary by the [South Shore Line](http://www.nictd.com/).  It's much more convenient actually than to make it to Chicago.  Could you email me please?

Comment: @wxffles China? Beijing?

Comment: @cormullion Beijing is 6,700 miles from Champaign, not 8,600.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom This sounds very, very interesting but since I'm not giving a speech and Krakow is quite far away from Champaign I'm not favorite to get sponsorship :) Also, I should book the fly tickets and get the visa now but I can't risk that I will have to pay for it myself, tough student life :P But give me a week, I have to think, maybe I will find an option :)

Comment: @wxffles Dunedin, New Zealand?  (8593 miles, according to `GeoDistance`.)

Comment: @BrettChampion Correct!  You win a prize.  I might post you an albatross or something.

Comment: @wxffles ohhh, can I get one too, I want one badly, ever since [the rescuers](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rescuers)?

Comment: Albatrosses for everyone!

Comment: I'm booked. I enjoyed 2012 and 2013 I'm in again.

Answer (score 19):

OK I'd like to attend the Wolfram Technology Conference and would like to be sponsored by Mathematica Stack Exchange community.  As I only live a few hundred miles north of Wolfram HQ, I plan on attending this conference to gain a small portion of the knowledge my mentors here have been sharing with me, in hopes that I could do the same for others here on MMSE.  I have been active on MMSE for quite some time and there's not a day that goes by where I don't find some new tip or trick in the questions and answers here.   On the drive down I plan to pick up Szabolcs on the way to make sure another SE member also get's to experience the speakers and teaching available at this conference. I'm also looking forward to meeting and networking with other users and feel comfortable explaining my experiences with the benefits of MMSE over even Wolfram Support in some cases. I plan to [blog](http://pixelologie.com/) & [tweet](https://twitter.com/PIXELOLOGIE) about my experience, as I believe this will be an amazing time of interest to all the MMSE community.  Thanks for your consideration!

Comment: I'd like to hear more about your experiences in the imaging field, so you have my upvote.

Comment: @rcollyer I fixed the links to the website. The information your requesting is available at the bottom of the front page.

Comment: Cool. I used to work for a large copier/printer manufacturer, and I get curious every once in a while.

Comment: Did you get any feedback from SE yet? Seems like your application would be the one to go with...

Comment: @YvesKlett Yes SE is covering the hotel and conference costs.  Meals and travel are mine.  Thanks!

Comment: @RHall Excellent! Breakast and lunch and one dinner are included anyway :-) Looking forward to your coverage and have a jolly good time!

Comment: Cool. See you there.

Comment: @RHall how´s the conference so far?

Comment: @YvesKlett Amazing cool new things coming to Mathematica 10! New blog post about day one posted here: https://pixelologie.com/?page_id=165

Comment: @RHall I say! Well done, thanks for the very informative and entertaining blog!

Comment: @YvesKlett   Wolfram called today to ask me to remove most of my blog posts, because they violated the NDA everyone had to sign to pick up your badge.  Seems they were supposed to inform us that everything was covered under NDA during each session but did not, so oops,  I quickly apologized and removed the information they requested.  They also told me that future conference will be the same, so if we sponsor another member next year blogging and tweeting shouldn’t be a suggested requirement.  Totally great conference though! Thanks everyone for voting me in!